# What is the difference between reportgenerator and BIRTreportgenerator?

Tags: fortify, reportgenerator, sourceanalyser

Is BIRTreportgenerator just a newer approach to reportgenerator?
Or are there differences to what they report and their intended use.

Answer (score 0):

[ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) is all about code coverage. If you want to visualize the code coverage of your tests, then ReportGenerator might be relevant for you.

BIRTreportgenerator seems to be a tool to perform static code analysis.